# How I can hide or change a url in anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when i click on this link the url on page.php is http://localhost/1/page.php?id=1&edition=muzzaffarabad&dt=09-08-2017. i want that after passing these parameters only edition name will show on url .like  http://localhost/1/muzzaffarabad

this is anchor tag i m using

```
<a class='imgFrame' href='page.php?id=1&edition=muzzaffarabad&dt=<?php echo $paper_set["muzzaffarabad_date"]?>'>
```

Comment: .Do you need id & dt?

Comment: Why do you want that? You know this does not increase “security” in any way, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just make your a tag like this:

```
<a onclick="changeHref()" class='imgFrame' href='page.php?id=1&edition=muzzaffarabad&dt=<?php echo $paper_set["muzzaffarabad_date"]?>'>
```

Then in your javascript file add function

```
function changeHref() {
    $(".imgFrame").attr("href", "http://localhost/1/muzzaffarabad");
}
```

Comment: "(click)="changeHref()"" does it suppose to be an angular template?

Comment: Sorry, I was working with angular and it was like habit.... Edited my answer, hope it helps and it's what you want..

Comment: Though I'm not sure because the question is too broad I think OP wants something different. He wants to send params to the server but hide them in url.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko yes same i want

Comment: @YousafFarooq The real question is why you want it :)

Comment: the boss told me to do that :)